# How do I restore the model when user clicks "Cancel" in a sheet?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a sheet with some editing fields in it, each bound to an attribute in my model, for editing.

[image: Screenshot]

Thus, the model is directly modified as the user makes changes in the sheet.

How should I restore the model if the user clicks "Cancel" on the sheet?

In my research I think I've seen people using NSUndoManager for this, but I'm not eager for that level of complexity at this stage if I can avoid it.

Or have I architected this wrong in a more fundamental way?

I'm using storyboards and aiming for 10.10+, if that's relevant.

Comment: You can save the value when the editing begins and then just restore it when the user hits cancel.

Comment: Is this sheet an NSWindow that you threw a cancel and OK button on?

Comment: The sort of control you show makes sense when you are creating a new object.  In code, you create a new object, and bind the fields to it.  If "save" is clicked, you save it into a collection.   If "Cancel" is clicked, you discard the object.   If this control is for editing an existing object, you would ideally have a pane with no buttons making it clear that edits are immediately persisted, with multiple levels of Undo available.

Comment: But if this is truly what you want, @rocky suggests the straightforward way.  There are a couple other ways to do the same thing by making a scratchpad which you throw away unless save is clicked...  Make a deep copy of the object being edited.  Bind to that.  Overwrite the original if save is clicked.   Or, if you're using core data, use a child context for the sheet, and only save it to the parent if save is clicked.

Comment: @AO — the sheet is a scene in my storyboard. Being a scene, it's an NSViewController. And yes, I just threw those buttons on. Being new at this, you're making me nervous asking questions like this :p Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks rocky and stevesliva for your input. I think I do want this UX. I really didn't think the answer would be a deep clone but I definitely respect your experience. I'm nervous that replacing an object with a completely new one (even if it's much the same) is going to have all kinds of side-effects elsewhere in the app, but I guess that's just something I need to keep in mind throughout.

Comment: I was only asking to see if you had an IBAction bound to the cancel button (Which it sounds like you would have to).  Just follow rocky's advice and save the value into a property when you display the sheet.  Then in the implementation of the cancelPressed, restore the value